# Read all files, change content, save again

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a replace in content of all files in a certain directory structure.

```
get-childItem temp\*.* -recurse |
    get-content |
    foreach-object {$_.replace($stringToFind1, $stringToPlace1)} |
    set-content [original filename]
```

Can I get the filename from the original get-childItem to use it in the set-content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add processing for each file:

```
get-childItem *.* -recurse | % `
{
    $filepath = $_.FullName;
    (get-content $filepath) |
        % { $_ -replace $stringToFind1, $stringToPlace1 } |
        set-content $filepath -Force
}
```

Key points:

1. `$filepath = $_.FullName;` — get path to file
2. `(get-content $filepath)` — get content and *close* file
3. `set-content $filepath -Force` — save modified content

Comment: The script asks for a parameter when the first foreach is followed by a newline. Fixed this by moving the first curly brace to the same line, but now it says the $ of the filepath parameter is not recognized

Comment: sample has been fixed: added ` and `$_`

Comment: Combined your answer with @Dan's. Marked yours as answer for the added context. Thx :)

Comment: btw, do not forget to use `get-content` and `set-content` with explicit specified encoding, for  example `-encoding utf8` or other

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `$_`, but you need a `foreach-object` around each file, too.  While @akim's answer will work, the use of `$filepath` is unnecessary:

```
gci temp\*.*  -recurse | foreach-object { (Get-Content $_) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $stringToFind1, $stringToPlace1 } | Set-Content $_ }
```

Comment: I think you've missed a closing bracket.

Comment: Combined your answer with @akim's