# Running a script block for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

When running the part below through PowerShell prompt, it does what it is supposed to do - change anything that contains `MYID` to `MyValue`.

```
(Get-Content C:/tmp/test.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "MYID", "MyValue"} | Set-Content C:/tmp/test.txt
```

Yet when I'm running it through a script block like below, it fails:

```
PowerShell Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Content C:/tmp/test.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "MYID", "MyValue"} | Set-Content C:/tmp/test.txt}
```

Below is the trace of the command above

> λ powershell invoke-command -scr {get-content c:\tmp\test.txt | foreach-object {$_ -replace "MYID", "MyValue"} | set-content c:\tmp\test.txt}
>   'foreach-object' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
>   ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I tried to do diverses variations like the one below

```
 powershell invoke-command -scr {(get-content c:\tmp\test.txt) | (foreach-object {$_ -replace "MYID", "MyValue"}) | (set-content c:\tmp\test.txt)}
```

The command above, gives me the following error

> } was not expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: "But each time, I have issues." _what issues_? Please post relevant error messages and descriptions of the unexpected behavior you're seeing

Comment: hi @MathiasR.Jessen see the update. Thanks

Comment: Try: `powershell -Command "& {get-content 'c:\tmp\test.txt' | foreach-object {$_ -replace 'MYID', 'MyValue'} | set-content 'c:\tmp\test.txt'}"`

Comment: Hi @JohnLBevan, it gives me this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJF2p.png What it says is the file is being used by another process therefore it cannot write on it. Yet the file is closed. I created an another file and same thing.

Comment: Ah; that's your process; Get-Content reads the first line, passes it down the pipeline to be changed, then Set-Content tries to write it and fails because Get-Content still has the file open for reading.

Comment: Stick brackets around the `Get-Content` bit so it reads all lines and closes the file before passing them on down the pipeline (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11794541/361842), or else read the data from a variable / write to a temp file then rename / etc; any solution which avoids writing to the file whilst it's still open for reading.

Comment: @JohnLBevan you're the man. Please put your answer, I will accept it

Comment: No worries; @BenN's on it already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `Invoke-Command` or a script block if you just want to execute a command on the local machine under normal conditions. Rather, we can just use the `-Command` switch to PowerShell:

```
powershell -command "(get-content c:\tmp\test.txt) | foreach-object { $_ -replace 'MYID', 'MyValue' } | set-content c:\tmp\test.txt"
```

Note the single quotes around the `-replace` strings; this avoids problems with the command processor's escaping. This command works on my machine with a multiline file, but if it gives you trouble with the file still being open, you can use this version, which reads the file in full rather than line by line:

```
powershell -c "(get-content c:\tmp\test.txt -raw) -replace 'MYID', 'MyValue' | set-content c:\tmp\test.txt -nonewline"
```